# Setting up email for drupal application for linode 12.04

Tags: mail

I've installed ubuntu server 12.04 with linode.

What do i need to install to allow my application to be able to send email in and out? Or is this package natively setup with ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out. I tailed the apache log and it indicated that /usr/bin/sendmail was not found.

In order to fix this, you just need to install exim:

`sudo apt-get install exim4-daemon-light mailutils; dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`

Source: [Linode](http://library.linode.com/email/exim/send-only-mta-ubuntu-11.04-natty#sph_configure-exim-for-local-mail-service)